# How can reduce font size of web when display on Android?

Tags: html, css

I create a web page for mobile phone:
i using this code:

```
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1" />
<style type="text/css">
    body {
        font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        font-size: 16px;
        -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
    }
</style>

<body>
    <table>
        ....
    </table>
</body>
```

**Result :**

**With IOS (IPhone 5s , 640 x 1136px):** The display is fine,

**But Android  (Nexus 5x ,1080 x 1920 px):** The font size seems larger

How can reduce font size of web when display on Android ?

[image]

Comment: Have you inspected element to see if it does not have actually bigger font (by css rules)?

Comment: You need to write media queries for different device resolution. Usually media queries for width property. Visit https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp and learn about responsive design.

Comment: `-webkit-text-size-adjust` Does this a valid property?

Comment: Have you tried using the `em` or `rem` units for font sizing? Also which resolutions are both emulators on?

Answer (score 0):

use @media in your css to manage this problem

```
@media screen and (max-width: 992px) {
    body {
        font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        font-size: 16px;
        -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
    }
}
```

for more information see [@media](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp)